# Tests work in Postman collection, but showing 0 execution in Newman

Tags: azure, azure-devops, postman, newman

I have used the Newman plugin in Azure DevOps to run the test. The tests are running fine in Postman and I have exported the JSON files to use with Newman in CI Pipeline.

I tried to install Newman's latest version 5.2.2 and also 4.6.1 but I am getting the result not correct.

[image]

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? A sample project is better.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it seems like you have saved environment.json as collection.json . Thats why you get everything as '0'

Make sure your collection.json file is correct and you haven't mistakenly replaced collection file with environment file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any file upload functionalities? from my end i had. To fix it I added the `--working-dir` option